# print data form List of Maps flutter/

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to print **startTime**  form this Map of decodedData.
I am new to flutter .
I need startTime so that I can show the time slots for availability.

```
Map decodedData = { "sts" : "SUCCESS", "data" : [{
                  
                    "startTime": 1665392445000,
                  "between": 1665414045000
                  },
                  {
                    "startTime": 1665414045000,
                     "between": 1665414045000
                  },
                ]};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 List<String> arrayStartTime = (decodedData["data"] as List<Map<String,dynamic>>).map((e) => "${e['startTime']}").toList();
```

result:

[1665392445000, 1665414045000]

You can set array int or String type as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

You must try this :

```
 decodedData["data"]).values.forEach((v) => print("startTime = 
    ${v["startTime"]}"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use decodedData[0]['startTime'] and so on, you can also use for loop.
and use
**DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(decodedData[0]['startTime'],isUtc: true).toString()** to print it or format it as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Map decodedData = { "sts" : "SUCCESS", "data" : [{
                    "slotKey": "1665392445000_|_1665394245000",
                    "startTime": 1665392445000,
                    "endTime": 1665394245000,
                    "isbooked": true,
                    "bookedBy": "qxWESdGsHvhywe3S7FxDeO2"
                  },
                  {
                    "slotKey": "1665414045000_|_1665415845000",
                    "startTime": 1665414045000,
                    "endTime": 1665415845000,
                    "isbooked": false
                  },
                ]};

void main(){
  for(var item in decodedData["data"]){
    print("startTime = ${item["startTime"]}");
}
}
```